# Nodejs return result from function is empty promise

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, return, tron

I am trying to use Nodejs tron library to create pair of wallet address and here is my code:

app.js

```
var app = require('express')()
var http = require('http').createServer(app)
var wallet_engine = require('./function')
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    result = wallet_engine.create_wallet_trx()
    console.log(result)
    res.send(result)
})
//////server listen
http.listen(8443, function () {
    console.log('listening on *:8443')
})
```

and here is my function.js

```
module.exports = {
    create_wallet_trx: function () {
////////generate TRX Address
        var { HdTronPayments } = require('@faast/tron-payments')
        var keys = HdTronPayments.generateNewKeys()
        var tronPayments = new HdTronPayments({ hdKey: keys.xprv })
        var address = tronPayments.getPayport(356)
        var privateKey = tronPayments.getPrivateKey(356)
        var trx_wallet = { privateKey: privateKey, address: address }
        console.log(trx_wallet)
        return trx_wallet
    },
}
```

The problem is when i check  console.log(trx_wallet) the result is there and i can see generated public and private key, also after returning data, console.log(result) is displaying data, but res.send(result) shows me empty json.

this is console.log() results

```
{
  privateKey: Promise {
    'B88BB56DAB80DB681765A0C07197DD23BB8E2FAD195BF9D0ECD09F5F8FC54297'
  },
  address: Promise { { address: 'TYCJSKERHReUXacw9wLorZYLDoijevvsVK' } }
}
```

and this is the result on my browser:

```
{"privateKey":{},"address":{}}
```

i know this is because of Nodejs Async system and i should wait to promise gets the value but i don't know how to wait for promise to get complete and then prints the result on my browser screen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: They are promise objects which you are trying to `JSON.stringify`. Wait for their results, then send those.

Comment: You cannot trust the output of `console.log`, at least not what you see when you *expand* it, because that part the console will often retrieve asynchronously... later.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i tried the aproach from your provided link before but it caused the browser to load forever. i did it like:  `wallet_engine.create_wallet_trx(function(result) {
   res.send(result)
  }); `

Comment: Are you sure the API you're working with accepts callbacks like that? That wouldn't be conventional for Node, and the function you show doesn't handle any arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing good but here many calls are asynchronous that's for you facing problem. 
you should use `async await or then` as i did bellow it may help you..

```js
// app js


var app = require('express')()
var http = require('http').createServer(app)
var wallet_engine = require('./function')
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    result = wallet_engine.create_wallet_trx().then(data=>{
      res.json(data);
    }).catch(err=>{
      console.log(err);
    })
})
//////server listen
http.listen(8443, function () {
    console.log('listening on *:8443')
})



// function.js

var { HdTronPayments } = require('@faast/tron-payments')

module.exports = {
  create_wallet_trx: async function () {
      var keys = await HdTronPayments.generateNewKeys()
      var tronPayments = await new HdTronPayments({ hdKey: keys.xprv })
      var address = await tronPayments.getPayport(356)
      var privateKey = await tronPayments.getPrivateKey(356)
      var trx_wallet = { privateKey: privateKey, address: address }
      return trx_wallet
  }
}
```

result: {"privateKey":"92ACAECFE00E9F90E330A6B031F10365F29AFDD503922CC99CA8704F1BA53432","address":{"address":"TGfsHx4VU6B36AwUy8Bqt6edoNnUHpMtSQ"}}

Comment: Thanks Atul it did the job.

Comment: Seems unlikely that all four awaits are necessary. Try omitting the first two leaving `var address = await tronPayments.getPayport(356)` and `var privateKey = await tronPayments.getPrivateKey(356)`.